# Can we define different colors for the same value on x and y axes?

Tags: plotting

Simply, I would like to generate a such figure

[image]

Note that zero along y and x has different colors (White and Black), how can we do that? or there is another trick?

```
DensityPlot[x (Cos[\[Pi] y]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 200, FrameTicks -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An approximation to the figure in the OP can be drawn as follow.

```
Graphics[Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 
    0}, {0, -1}, {0.5, -1}, {1, -1}}, 
  VertexColors -> {Black, Red, Blend[{Red, White}], White, White, 
    White, Blend[{White, Blue}], Blue}]
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]